# MFC radio button group message handler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, radio-button

I've got two little questions at Visual Studio MFC-GUI programming technique regarding the handling of a group of radio buttons in VS2015 CE.

I have a little dialog based application. This application draws some lines on my dialog with a specified pen.
Now I made a group of radio buttons to be able do use different colors for the pen. So I created a group box, placed the radio buttons into this group box, enabled the group property of the first radio button and checked the tab sequence so that all of the radio buttons are properly in sequence.

That's ok - testing the GUI I'm able to select just one of the radio button as planned, because I wouldn't be able to draw a line in to different colors at the same time. Now I added an handler for the BN_CLICKED Message of the first radio button object in the ClassWizard to add the selection of different colored pens.

Now comes the interesting part. This handler is executed only when i click the first radio button. The one with group property enabled. I thought it should be executed whenever I click any of the radio buttons in this group. The next thing I tried was to add an BN_CLICKED-Messagehandler to all of those radio buttons, but the ClassWizard does not shows the BN_CLICKED Message for the other radio buttons - only for the one with group proerty enabled.

After googling around I read a post that one would be able to add an BN_CLICKED-Messagehandler for an button by simply double clicking it in the Dialog. So I double clicked all of my radio buttons and added an invocation of the BN_CLICKED-Messagehandler of the first radio button. That's working as a workaround so that now my line is drawn in the different colors whenever I click on any of those radio buttons (black, blue, red , and so on).

I have two questions - is this behaviour intended? I suppose the reason why I'm only able to add a BN_CLICKED-Messagehandler in the ClassWizard for the first radio button is, that it would be invoked by any of the radio buttons in my group, wouldn't it?

Another question is, I would have preferred to write the handler once and be able to tell the class wizard to use this particular handler instead of creating a unique handler for each of the buttons. That's independent of this radio buttons. I tested this with a simple application which consists of an assembly of several buttons - which can have their own BN_CLICKED-Messagehandlers attached by the class wizard. When I didn't accept the automatically generated functionname from the wizard and enter the name of my own handlerfunction it simply states that it wouldn't be able to overwrite it. How can I select an existing handler for an object message in the class wizard or is that not possible and I have to do this manually in code for myself?

Hope there's an VS2015 MFC Guy out there be able to tell me ..

Comment: Just add the handlers by hand, it works fine.

Comment: In between Visual Studio 6 and Visual Studio 2010 we had no MFC Class Wizard. It's a convenience, and you need to be prepared to write MFC code without it. Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC, Second Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950) is recommended reading. It explains what is behind all those macros and auto-generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed by design. You could have wanted different behaviour for each button click - if you don;t simply associate all of the BN_CLICKED to the same message handler and delete the ones that were automatically generated.
You can also use ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, id1, id2, memberFxn ) - make sure your buttons are in the same range in your resource.h
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank's. A pity that this couldn't be solved with a build in functionailty of the class wizard. But that ON_CONTROL_RANGE Makro you mentioned seems to be definitely worth looking at. Although the definition of the control ids seems to be a little bit difficult. I just read a few examples and the definiftion at MSDN. I'll give it a try.